# How to make this xml query shorter

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I spent 3 days to read this xml file and put the details in to the database. It works the way it should be but I know the way i read this xml file is not the proper way.

If the xml file is bigger than 2mb. (which contains about 1000 records), it takes more than 1 minute to load.

Can you please show me how to make this query shorter.

this is the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<outputTree xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/software/analytics/spss/xml/oms" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.ibm.com/software/analytics/spss/xml/oms http://www.ibm.com/software/analytics/spss/xml/oms/spss-output-1.8.xsd">
    <command command="Summarize" displayOutlineValues="label" displayOutlineVariables="label" displayTableValues="label" displayTableVariables="label" lang="en" text="Summarize">
        <pivotTable subType="Report" text="Batch">
            <dimension axis="row" text="Cases">
                <group label="Test Site" text="Test Site" varName="PLANT_DESC" variable="true">
                    <group hide="true" text="A">
                        <group string="A" text="A" varName="PLANT_DESC">
                            <group label="Product" text="Product" varName="PROD_DESC" variable="true">
                                <group hide="true" text="A">
                                    <group string="S" text="S" varName="PROD_DESC">
                                        <group label="Batch Number" text="Batch Number" varName="BATCH_NO" variable="true">
                                            <group hide="true" text="A">
                                                <group number="3704542" text="3704542" varName="BATCH_NO">
                                                    <category number="1" text="1">
                                                        <dimension axis="column" text="Variables">
                                                            <category label="Batch Run" text="Batch Run" varName="BATCH_RUN_ID" variable="true">
                                                                <cell number="4202" text="4202" varName="BATCH_RUN_ID"/>
                                                            </category>
                                                            <category label="Application" text="Application" varName="APP_ID" variable="true">
                                                                <cell label="Calibration" number="101" text="Calibration" varName="APP_ID"/>
                                                            </category>
                                                            <category label="Date Tested" text="Date Tested" varName="TEST_DATE" variable="true">
                                                                <cell date="2014-09-23T10:53:19" format="date" text="23-SEP-2014" varName="TEST_DATE"/>
                                                            </category>
                                                        </dimension>
                                                    </category>
                                                </group>            
                                            </group>
                                        </group>
                                    </group>                                            
                                </group>
                            </group>
                        </group>
                    </group>
                </group>
            </dimension>
        </pivotTable>
    </command>
</outputTree>
```

This is the c#

```
XElement root = XElement.Load(Page.Server.MapPath(@"oril.xml"));
XNamespace ad = "http://www.ibm.com/software/analytics/spss/xml/oms";

var cats = from cat in root.Descendants(ad + "dimension").Where
               (cat => (string)cat.Attribute("axis") == "column" && (string)cat.Attribute("text") == "Variables")

           select new
           {
               BATCH_NO = cat.Parent.Parent.Attribute("number").Value,
               RUN_NO = cat.Parent.Attribute("number").Value,

               //// 1
               BATCH_RUN_ID = cat.Descendants(ad + "category").Elements(ad + "cell")
                    .Where(a => (string)a.Attribute("varName") == "BATCH_RUN_ID")
                    .Select(c => c.Attribute("number").Value),

               //// 2
               APP_ID = cat.Descendants(ad + "category").Elements(ad + "cell")
                    .Where(a => (string)a.Attribute("varName") == "APP_ID")
                    .Select(c => c.Attribute("label").Value),

               //// 3
               TEST_DATE = cat.Descendants(ad + "category").Elements(ad + "cell")
                       .Where(a => (string)a.Attribute("varName") == "TEST_DATE")
                       .Select(c => c.Attribute("date").Value),
               ////
               //// Another 12
               ////
           };

foreach (var cat in cats)
{
    foreach (string s in cat.BATCH_RUN_ID)
    {
        xmlTitle.Text += "BATCH_NO: " + cat.BATCH_NO + " </br>";
        xmlTitle.Text += "RUN_NO: " + cat.RUN_NO + " </br>";
        xmlTitle.Text += "BATCH_RUN_ID: " + s + " </br>";
    }

    foreach (string s in cat.APP_ID)
    {
        xmlTitle.Text += "APP_ID: " + s + " </br>";
        i_APP_ID = s;
    }
    foreach (string s in cat.TEST_DATE)
    {
        xmlTitle.Text += "TEST_DATE: " + s + " </br>";
        i_TEST_DATE = s;
    }
    foreach (string s in cat.CB_USED)
    {
        xmlTitle.Text += "CB_USED: " + s + " </br>";
        i_CB_USED = s;
    }
    ////
    //// Another 12
    ////
}
```

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: perhaps you can use the [xsd tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(v=vs.110).aspx) to generate a class for your xml and then use [xml deserialization](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/483055/XML-Serialization-and-Deserialization-Part) to get the object from your xml file. traversing the in-memory object should be faster than parsing the xml file using the reader.

Comment: If the file is that large, the issue is likely how you're reading the file in from the file system, not how you're processing it (though that may be able to be improved also).  Have you looked into buffering the contents of the file into memory and perhaps using something other than XElement? Have a read here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647804.aspx

Comment: Also, the attitude at MS is changing (for the better).  Here, you can take a look at the underlying implementation of the method you're using: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Xml.Linq/XLinq.cs.html

Comment: Your use of `cat` as a variable for a `dimension` is confusing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Objects, since this is an Object Oriented Language, to ease some of your `.Descendants().Elements()` pain.

```
public class Category
{
    public readonly XElement self;
    public readonly XNamespace ns;
    public Category(XNamespace xn, XElement cat) { self = cat; ns = xn; }
    public string Name { get { return (string)self.Attribute("varName"); } }
    public Cell Cell { get { return _Cell ?? (_Cell = new Cell(self.Elements(ns+"cell").First())); } }
    Cell _Cell;
}

public class Cell
{
    public readonly XElement self;
    public Cell(XElement cell) { self = cell; }
    public string Name { get { return (string)self.Attribute("varName"); } }
    public string Number { get { return (string)self.Attribute("number"); } }
    public string Date { get { return (string)self.Attribute("date"); } }
    public string Label { get { return (string)self.Attribute("label"); } }
}

public class Dimension
{
    public readonly XElement self;
    public readonly XNamespace ns;
    public Dimension(XNamespace xn, XElement dim) { self = dim; ns = xn; }
    public string Axis { get { return (string)self.Attribute("axis"); } }
    public string Text { get { return (string)self.Attribute("text"); } }
    public string BatchNo { get { return self.Parent.Parent.Attribute("number").Value } }
    public string RunNo { get { return self.Parent.Attribute("number").Value } }
    public Category[] Categories
    { get { return _Categories ?? (_Categories = self.Elements(ns + "category")
                             .Select(cat => new Category(ns, cat))
                             .ToArray()); }
    }
    Category[] _Categories;
}
```

Then to use your `root` and `ad` defined in your post. If nothing else, it is more readable,
but it should be faster since once a Cell is created in a Category, it doesn't need to find it
on every cell call. And likewise with each category in a dimension.

```
var dims = root.Descendants(ad + "dimension")
               .Select(dim => new Dimension(ad, dim))
               .Where(Dim => Dim.Axis == "column" && Dim.Text == "Variables");
var cats = dims.Select(dim => new
{
    BATCH_NO = dim.BatchNo,
    RUN_NO = dim.RunNo,

    //// 1
    BATCH_RUN_ID = dim.Categories
                      .Where(cat => cat.Name == "BATCH_RUN_ID")
                      .Select(cat => cat.Cell.Number),
    //// 2
    APP_ID = dim.Categories
                      .Where(cat => cat.Name == "APP_ID")
                      .Select(cat => cat.Cell.Label),

    //// etc
}
```

ps I typed this manually, it may not directly compile as is, but it would be something simple like a missing `;`

Comment: waww, about 8 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

**First thing first,**

when you need to concat alot of loop String like that you need to use StringBuilder to help it first

```
example:
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach (var cat in cats)
{
    foreach (string s in cat.BATCH_RUN_ID)
    {
        //xmlTitle.Text += "BATCH_NO: " + cat.BATCH_NO + " </br>";
        sb.append("BATCH_NO: ");
        sb.append( cat.BATCH_NO );
        sb.append(" </br>");
        // more and more, without using String + String
    }
}

//at the end of the loop, just put it back to xml text
xmlTitle.Text = sb.toString();
```

Comment: thanks alot. I have got the xmlTitle, to see if i have got the correct output. I will delete that. The problem is the foreach loop. I have got too many of them.